# C# catching base custom exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I am struggling to find a solution for something I am facing.

I have several exception classes, which all derive from one base class. The base class itself derives from System.Exception.

So finally I have for example **BadRequestException** : **BaseException** : **Exception**.

When I throw a **BadRequestException** however, I cannot catch it using a catch for BaseException, but instead it is being caught by the generic **Exception**. Why is that? Am I doing something wrong or this is just not possible?

Comment: Could you please show the exact code so we can try to reproduce this? (though I think it will not be reproducible, but to tell you why it happens on your machine, we need a [mcve]).

Comment: Where do you throw a BadRequestException? Can you show a code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the issue. My exceptions have a generic enum argument and in that case I was throwing the exception for one enum and catching it for a different one. Sorry for disturbing all of you.